# OpenID doesn't let me into to Area51

Tags: support, login

When I go to Area 51, and log in there with stack exchange, I get this error.

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
The openid.return_to parameter (lengthy URL redacted)
does not match the actual URL (lengthy URL redacted)
the request was made with.
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug somewhere?

Comment: Please let me know if you need any more information. I removed those URLs since they might have sensitive info in them, I don't know.

Comment: Area 51 used to run an older version of the SE software. This may still be the case, and account for some friction between Area 51 and the normal SE sites.

Answer (score 6):

The URL you redacted is actually the important part of the message. If you look at them you'll notice one is HTTP and the other is HTTPS. Those URLs don't match, so the system kicks it out as suspicious.

This is caused by starting the login process via the HTTP version of the site, while having some sort of extension (such as HTTPS Everywhere) that automatically rewrites the path back to an HTTPS link, which no longer matches the URL that the site was expecting back (it has an extra "s" in it).

At some point, Area 51 will start forcing HTTPS connections always and this problem will be obsolete. For now, you can simply make sure you are on the HTTPS version of the site before starting the login process, so that the site expects the HTTPS path when you get back. You could also temporarily disable the extension.

Comment: The problem will be obsolete by July 1st due to OpenID being dropped.

Comment: If only we could make it HTTPS sooner so I don't have to keep typing this at people for another three months. ;P